# send information to another class

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning java and I have a problem, I'm working on library system and can't figure out how to send information about created user to list(hashMap) of users...

On the picture below is my code, in red circle admin call method to create librarian. Problem is I can't figure out how to send information about this to blue circle to add this new librarian to list of users... I thought I would move hashMap activeUsers to class admin but i need librarians to create customers as well so...

[image]

any idea please?

Comment: code is missing, no picture either

Comment: You create a new 1) `Hashmap e.g HashMap m = new HashMap(); `2) Put Objects in the map with key/values. 3) Create instance of that class where your list(hashMap) method is define like `ClassAInLibraryX abc = new ClassAInLibraryX();` ... or whatever the parameter of constructor is and then call `abc.list(m)`;

Comment: Do not post code or logs as screenshots post it as text

Comment: Just add a static modifier on addUser method. Then you could use it from Admin class like `LibraryMain.addUser(usr,psw);` Also, activeUsers HashMap has package access. Assuming all of your classes are in the same package, you could use it this way `LibraryMain.activeUsers.put("","");` See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the variables public, so you can access to them from all the other classes, or you could write methods that return their value that you can call from any other class. You can find more information [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/%40peterekeneeze/passing-data-between-activities-2d0ef122f19d&ved=2ahUKEwiW7KfZ4YnmAhVBCewKHZChDwQQFjAKegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw21onVbE8fHWEXXagA0Sz0R) too, if you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can try  addUser(l.name, l.psw) in createLibrarian() function. Thanks